# How to preserve tissue DNA without using formalin?

Tags: dna

Except using formalin to preserve human corpse for autopsy. I heard from the news that technique damages the DNA in the organs

**Question:**
Suppose corpse will be investigated next by another juridical unit
Do we have any other techniques which are better than this?
For example like freezing in the fridge. Because police office needs all above questions to complete his case.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I think this question is off-topic as it's clearly not about biology. I don't think there should be an `autopsy` tag.

Comment: @Michael_A I got it. I just update my question to be more focusing on DNA preservation.

Comment: you may want to look into actual police preservation techniques, formalin is only used for certain organs after removal in special circumstances, not the entire body nor all samples.

Comment: I'd suggest removing all mentions of `investigators` and `murder`; it distracts from your title question about preserving DNA without using formalin. You have provided three numbered questions that an investigator might want to answer but 2 and 3 are not about biology.

Comment: @Michael_A I have updated my question and remove 2 and 3 out because it beyonds the scopes of SE Biology